# Deploy appx package to custom emulator created using XDE cli

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-mobile, windows-phone-emulator, windows-mobile-emulator

I have created a new Windows Phone 8.1 emulator using XDE cli ([see msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/notime/archive/2013/04/21/shortcut-to-start-windows-phone-8-emulator.aspx))

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.1\XDE.exe" /vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd" /video "720x1280" /memsize 1024 /language 409 /creatediffdisk "%TEMP%\dd.720x1280.1024.vhd" /fastShutdown
```

Is there a way to deploy appx packages to this emulator using AppDeployCmd.exe or other tool? The created emulator does not show in the list of available devices in AppDeployCmd, only standard emulators are listed in the tool, same for Windows 10 Mobile.
Should the emulator be somehow registered in AppDeployCmd?

Comment: You can use Windows Phone Application Deployment tool to deploy the file to either emulator or in windows phone

Comment: Yes, but only to preset emulators or device. Windows Phone Application Deployment tool is a GUI version of AppDeployCmd.exe. What I need is to deploy app to custom emulator created with XDE cli. So that I can create more than one emulators with 512 Mb RAM or to create emulator with preset boot language, video me, etc.